# Unable to print multi-line strings in C

Tags: c, string, multiline, curses, multilinestring

I am trying to print a series of multi-line strings (ascii art letters here), and when printing them out, the top of each letter moves to the right while the rest of the letter stays in the same position. Here is a screenshot of what occurs: [image: Error-image]

I do not know why this is happening, as I am fairly new to C; if you have any knowledge about this, please share it!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>

typedef const char letter[];


letter Y = 
"___      __\n
\\ \\__ / /\n
 \\ \\ / /\n
 |  |  |\n
 |  |  |\n
 |__|__|\n";

letter O =  
"_______ \n
/   __ \\\n
|  |  | |\n
|  |__| |\n
\\_______/\n";

letter U = 
" __    __ \n
 / |   | \\\n
|  |   |  |\n
|   \\_/   |\n
\\_________/\n";

letter L = 
" _\n"
"| |\n"  
"| |\n"
"| |__\n"
"|____/\n";

letter S =
" _________\n"
"/   _____/\n"
"\\_____  \\\n"
"/        \\\n"
"/_______  /\n"
"        \\/\n";

letter T =
"___________\n"
"\\__    ___/\n"
"   |   |\n"
"   |   |\n"
"   |___|\n";

letter EXCLAMATION_POINT =
"_________\n"
"\\\\\\\\|////\n"
" \\\\\\|///\n"
"  \\\\|//\n"
"   \\|/\n"
"   ***\n"
"   ***\n"
"    *\n";

const char *MESSAGE[] = {Y, O, U, L, O, S, T, EXCLAMATION_POINT};

int main() {
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();

    int maxY, maxX;
    getmaxyx(stdscr, maxY, maxX);

    int spacingPerLetter = maxX / 8;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        mvprintw(maxY / 2, spacingPerLetter * (i + 1), MESSAGE[i]);
        refresh();
        getch();
        clear();
    }

    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The letters `y`, `o`, and `u` have a lot of spaces after the newlines.  The others do not.  Why the difference?

Comment: `mvprintw` moves to the middle of the line before it prints. It then prints MESSAGE[i] (which includes several lines of text).  So the blank lines are coming from the `maxY / 2`.  Change that to 0.

Comment: You can't break a string declaration like this. (At least, not in any C compiler I've ever used.) In your definitions of Y, O and U, you should have a closing double quotation mark after each `\n` and an opening quote at the start of each following line.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is the newline embedded inside the strings you print.

The first "line" of the letters will be printed in the correct position, but then the newline will reset the position to the first column on the next line.

I recommend that you print each "letter" line by line (without the newlines). This could be helped by having each "letter" be an array *of arrays* of characters, where each sub-array is one line of the letter:

```
#define LETTER_WIDTH   11
#define LETTER_HEIGHT   6

const char Y[LETTER_HEIGHT][LETTER_WIDTH] = {
    "___      __",
    "\\ \\__ / /",
    " \\ \\ / / ",
    " |  |  |   ",
    " |  |  |   ",
    " |__|__|   "
};
```